# How to Extract Data from Array - PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I extract the field: `chat_id` from this array? I'm trying to put the chat_id in the id of a button in html.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => Armani
            [last_name] => Dee
            [contact_number] => 123456
            [email_address] => hello@gmail.com
            [home_address] => 
            [username] => armani
            [password] => 12345
            [status] => 0
            [email_confirmed] => 0
            [chat_id] => 14
            [admin_id] => 0
            [customer_id] => 2
            [partner_id] => 0
            [timestamp] => 2018-06-15 22:38:24
            [chat_exists] => 1
            [reply_id] => 208
            [message] => Hello 
            [timestamp_reply] => 2018-06-16 14:02:44
            [chat_status] => 0
        )

)
```

I got my output from my model:

```
public function chat_customer($enum) 
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('customer');
    $this->db->order_by('timestamp','desc');
    $this->db->where('customer.id',$enum);
    $this->db->join('chat','chat.customer_id = customer.id','left');
    $this->db->join('chat_reply', 'chat_reply.chat_id = chat.chat_id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Then I retrieved it in my controller like this:

```
 $customer_id = $this->input->get('message');
 $this->load->model('Crud_model');
 $data = $this->Crud_model->chat_customer($customer_id);
 echo print_r($data);
```

I'm trying to print the 14 on the chat_id.
 Thank you for your help!

Comment: `$var[0]->chat_id`

Comment: @Metalik Hi thank you for answering my question but I tried that already and I got an error that states undefined offset 0.

Comment: @pradeep Hi! I tried these but still no luck:                                                      
                echo $data['0']['chat_id'];
                echo $data['chat_id'];  
                echo $data->chat_id;

Comment: try with this `echo $data[0]->chat_id;`

Comment: @pradeep Thank you very much but still I got an error of  I got an error that states undefined offset 0.

Comment: How did you get the output in your question? Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: show what code u r using?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Hi Thank you! I already edited my question

Comment: @pradeep Thank you! Edit my question already

Comment: use `$query->row();` if u always return only row there

Comment: @pradeep OMG! Thank you! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Return data with `$query->row();` if it always return single row*

Your model should be like this :

```
public function chat_customer($enum) 
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('customer');
    $this->db->order_by('timestamp','desc');
    $this->db->where('customer.id',$enum);
    $this->db->join('chat','chat.customer_id = customer.id','left');
    $this->db->join('chat_reply', 'chat_reply.chat_id = chat.chat_id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

In your controller :

```
 $customer_id = $this->input->get('message');
 $this->load->model('Crud_model');
 $data = $this->Crud_model->chat_customer($customer_id);
 echo $data->chat_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a foreach loop if you are going to get multiple rows in your query.

```
foreach($data as $d){
  echo $d['column_name'];
}
```

This will make sure you iterate over all the rows.